# Ask do you add a property to a dynamic list in c#?

Tags: c#, list, dynamic

EXAMPLE: when you want to return an object in Json, you can create the object like this:

```
 Json(new { NameIWant= myProperty});
```

But in my dynamic list goes like this...

```
List<dynamic> list = new List<dynamic>();

var propertyName1 = 1000;
list.Add(number1);

var propertyName2 = 2000;
list.Add(number1);
```

This only contains the amount but I would like to add a name so my object in position [0] and position [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0Ejd.png) are named:

```
propertyName1 = 1000, 
propertyName2 =2000
```

Right now my list looks like this:
[image]

In other words I want to display a Name next to the [0] and [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0Ejd.png) so when I call them I don't use their position and I'll use their name instead.

Comment: Looks like you want a HashTable/Dictionary instead then.

Comment: You want your JSON to look like what? `{"list":["number1 = 1000", "number2 = 2000"]}` ??

Comment: C# is stronngly typed. Using dynamic to store ints in a list looks like abuse. Use Lists of objects if you need names. Or dictionaries, although they are not "ordered".

Comment: I want the properties of my List<dynamic>to have names. The Json was just an example of what I want

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution was as simple as this, I knew it was similar to creating a Json object :)

```
list.Add( new { NameOfProperty= Value });
```

Comment: and what ware those `Limit` and `Deductible` ?

Comment: The name of my property @PatrickArtner it was a very basic answer! you define the "NAME " and you asign the value after. simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

There is quite a few options available. Below some of them:

```
var propertyName1 = 1000;
var propertyName2 = 2000;

// List of key value pairs
var myList = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();
myList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>(nameof(propertyName1), propertyName1));
myList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>(nameof(propertyName2), propertyName2));

// Dictionary
var myDict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
myDict[nameof(propertyName1)] = propertyName1;
myDict[nameof(propertyName2)] = propertyName2;

// List of tuples
var myTupleList = new List<Tuple<string, int>>();
myTupleList.Add(new Tuple<string, int>(nameof(propertyName1), propertyName1));
myTupleList.Add(new Tuple<string, int>(nameof(propertyName2), propertyName2));
```

All examples are using strongly typed collections but it will work with `dynamic` too. Though, unless there is a very good reason I would stay with strongly typed collections.

[image]